# why vector in c++ address cannot access by raw pointer

Tags: c++, stl

when I'm using vector every time I write

```
    vector<int>::iterator itr;
```

but when I want to access address with raw pointer like

```
 int *ptr=v.begin();
```

it doesn't print anything  and show error 
if I want to print address with iterator and raw pointer variable 
it doesn't print any address
but if we want to access with v[i] like this it works fine
my question is why this raw pointer doesn't hold this container beginner address

Comment: Can you show a complete code example of what you tried instead of an english description of it? (i.e. what worked and what didnt?)

Comment: `begin()` returns an [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin). You need to dereference it and get the address of that value by `&*v.begin()` although it's just easier to use the method [`v.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get the pointer

Comment: I think it's duplicate as suggested @sshashank124

Comment: *"it doesn't print anything and show error"* That largely depends on how you're attempting to print it. Could you show us that please?

Comment: Why do you need that pointer anyway?

Comment: my question is why i use iterator instead of pointer is their any restriction to access v.begin() and v.end() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you'd like a pointer to the first element in the vector:

```
vector<int>::iterator itr = v.begin();
// if(itr != v.end()) // should be involved
int* ptr = &*itr;
```

Or:

```
// if(v.size()) // should be involved
```

```
int* ptr = &v[0]; // all C++ versions
```

```
int* ptr = v.data(); // C++11 and later
```

Comment: Actually my question is if i want to hold address with ptr than why it is showing error it acually point to address why it is necessar to use iterator

Comment: @hacksark As my second example shows, no iterator is needed.

Comment: i get confusion on iterator  if iterator itr is an object how it hold address

Comment: @hacksark Yes, an iterator instance is an object of its own. Well designed iterators are light-weight and should be considered for "copy-by-value". This is what you'll find in the standard library. `vector<int>::iterator itr = v.begin();` will probably be a `int*` if you look at the assembly code.

Comment: but how it equal to holding address

Comment: `template<typename T> struct iterator { T* addr; };` holds an address. It's just as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int *ptr=v.begin();
> ```

You cannot generally do this. `std::vector::begin` returns a `std::vector::iterator`, which is not guaranteed to be convertible to an `int*`. Even in a case where it happens to be convertible, there is no guarantee for what the converted value would be.

If what you want is the address of the first element of the vector, you can use the `data` member function:

```
int *ptr = v.data();
```